# How to customize tkinter windows explorer

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

```
from tkinter import filedialog

filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "H:/series/ghorbaghe",
                                      title = "Select a File",
                                      filetypes = (("Text files",
                                                    "*.txt*"),
                                                   ("all files",
                                                    "*.*")))
```

hi I want to know how to customize tkinter windows explorer.`tkinter\filedialog.py` has `askopenfilename` function and that one uses a window similar to 'windows explorer', but it has more built-in functions in order to return selected filename which is not my concern(the circled bar below), and I only care about the windows file explorer itself.

[image: tkinter's windows file explorer]

when 'windows explorer' shows a directory files, it iterates over files on that directory and shows them, and I want to know how to can I customize that 'windows explorer' to iterates over custom files (from anywhere regardless of path) and show them?!

so I want to customize the 'windows explorer' in the way when i give the files {'i1.jpg','i2.jpg'} to 'customize windows explorer' it just shows those files, and the addessbar will not be relevant or working.

Comment: So.. You want to customize the open file window?

Comment: @typedecker I want to customize the 'windows explorer' in the way when i give the files {'i1.jpg','i2.jpg'} to 'customize windows explorer' it just shows those files, and the addessbar will not be relevant or working.

Comment: You can achieve such an effect by creating your own toplevel widget and displaying all the files of a directory in a `ttk.Treeview` using `os.listdir`.